# When leaving Augmented Reality ViewController, Button doesnt detect touch until device is rotated

Tags: swift, xcode, ipad

I made a container view in which I put my Menu UI ViewController, embedded in multiples ViewControllers.

I'm using ARKit+CoreLocation and when leaving my view with Augmented Reality, a UIButton on the top left of my screen **doesn't register touches until I turn my device** in landscape or portrait mode... It still works if I turn back to my initial orientation.

(I'm testing on an iPad Pro 9.7)

[image: Image & Constraints screenshot]

Comment: Wow, sounds odd. Can you post more? Yes, I'm *not* an IB person - but seriously, anything done in IB can be done in code. What exactly are those 3 (4?) segues doing in your screenshot? One thought: strip things down to "bare minimum" to duplicate the issue. (A way of doing MVP.) See if you can give us that - a bare minimum, yet complete - way to duplicate your issue. Hopefully? You'll find the issue doing just that. And if so, please (a) edit your question with a more specific issue and (b) feel free to answer your question... I'd gladly upvote it.

Comment: My guess would be that the button is behind some other view. Try [debugging view hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html)

Comment: thx @dfd & @ pckill Found it. I'm using ARKit+CoreLocation and when i'm leaving the view, the images attached to my SCNNodes still exist and get in front of my button.